# PostgreSQL Unique constraint and compound index

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a unique constraint on two fields, I also use this as an index for faster performance. I want to query a third field as part of this index but I don't want the third field to be part of the unique constraint. i.e. I don't want a new composite index just for the third field as it's quite large.

Is there a way to do this in Postgres? I presently create the unique constraint and get the index created for free, can I specify the three-field composite index and tell the unique constraint to use this index, and Postgres will figure out it can use this index as a UC?

Comment: What do you mean by "*I want to query a third field as part of this index*"? If the first two fields already uniquely identify the row, there's no need to search further by a third field.

Comment: _"I want to query a third field as part of this index but I don't want the third field to be part of the unique constraint"_ Your question sounds a bit confusing - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Jack, have you tried using `INCLUDE`? Perhaps so the further filter (3rd column) might get quicker, as it is already loaded in the index. https://dbfiddle.uk/NI9zwVm_ Although @Bergi has a point: if the records are uniquely identifierd by the first two columns, there is no need to apply any other filter ;)

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the query and the index definition.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusing question. The third column will be used to filter a boolean, i.e. if sam(1st column) smith(2nd column) has brought apples(3rd column - boolean), assuming I have many sam smiths.

Comment: @jackwest Still doesn't make sense - if there's a unique constraint on the first two columns, you cannot have many Sam Smiths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INCLUDE option:

```
create unique index on the_table (column_1, column_2)
  include (column_3);
```

Comment: That won't help if you need the index to speed up queries with `column_3` in the `WHERE` clause.